# how to avoid waiting too long for the server's data when using recyclerview

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I managed to set up a recyclerview that displays server's data regarding some articles ( total 328 ).
The problem is the waiting time.
I have to wait about 40 seconds for the recyclerview to display completely.
Is there a way to display a small portion of this data directly without having to retrieve all the data ?
For instance, displaying data for the top 10 articles , scrolling down to the bottom , loading the next 10 articles and so on .. 
ANy recommendations ?

Comment: Implement pagination and only fetch 20 - 25 items at a time from the server.

Comment: https://blog.iamsuleiman.com/android-pagination-tutorial-getting-started-recyclerview/

Answer (score 0):

First of all, backend api should be able to provide results in a paginated way. So, when you load screen, you load first page. When you scroll down, you show a spinner and request the next page.

You can find a sample [here](https://blog.iamsuleiman.com/android-pagination-recyclerview-tutorial-api-retrofit-gson/)

Another point would be store articles in local database.

If you are using [Room library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room) as database, you can use the [pagination library](https://proandroiddev.com/8-steps-to-implement-paging-library-in-android-d02500f7fffe)

If you use another database, you have to implement your own solution.